# How to download music that stored in http server in Angularjs

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Let's say I have a API that stores some .mp3 music.
The sample link here:

> https://118.69.201.34:8882/api/ApiMusic/Download?songId=2000

Now I want to write an API calling function in Angularjs to download the music to my Android devices with the song's Id number as in the link.

How can I do that? Please help :(

Comment: Are you asking how to download files to device file system with ionic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ngCordova FileTransfer library here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Here's example code from that page, tweaked to your example URL:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

var fileid = "2000";
var url = "https://118.69.201.34:8882/api/ApiMusic/Download?songId=" + fileid;
var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + fileid + ".mp3";
var trustHosts = true
var options = {};

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
  .then(function(result) {
    // Success!
  }, function(err) {
    // Error
  }, function (progress) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
    })
  });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it finally, here is my code. Just share for those who want to refer to this issue in the future.  Thanks you guys for your answers

```
$scope.download = function(songId, songName) {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Downloading...'
    });
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
          fs.root.getDirectory(
              "fMusic",
              {
                create: true
              },
              function (dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile(
                    songName + ".mp3",
                    {
                      create: true,
                      exclusive: false
                    },
                    function gotFileEntry(fe) {
                      var p = fe.toURL();
                      fe.remove();
                      ft = new FileTransfer();
                      ft.download(
                          encodeURI(APIUrl + songId),
                          p,
                          function (entry) {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            $scope.mp3File = entry.toURL();
                          },
                          function (error) {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert("Download Error Source --> " + error.source);
                          },
                          false,
                          null
                      );
                    },
                    function () {
                      $ionicLoading.hide();
                      console.log("Get the file failed");
                    }
                );
              }
          );
        },
        function () {
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          console.log("Request for filesystem failed");
        });
  }
```